# Powershell: How to get powershell to give you the option to select the right user when you search with Known name

Tags: powershell, active-directory, powershell-3.0

I have creates a Powershell script that takes a display name from a CSV looks up there username and then adds them to a security group in AD.

The problem is people with the same Display name. My script when it hits the same display name it will just add every user name with that display name.

I would like an option when it hits a name that returns multiple username that it displays an option that allows someone to pick the right username then add them to the security group.

I am fairly new to PowerShell and have come a bit stuck at this point so any help is greatly appreciated.

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing")

$Form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$Form.Text = "Security Group Tool"
$Form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(390,150)
$Form.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"
$Form.KeyPreview = $True

$Form.MaximumSize = $Form.Size
$Form.MinimumSize = $Form.Size

$Icon = New-Object System.Drawing.Icon("H:\test\favicon.ico")
$Form.Icon = $Icon 

$label = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$label.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10, 10)
$label.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(400, 15)
$label.Text = "Please enter The name of the Security Group You want to add users too"
$Form.Controls.Add($label)

$textbox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$textbox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,50)
$textbox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(240,40)
$Form.Controls.Add($textbox)

$test = {

    $secgrp = $textbox.Text
    $Sam = @()
    $names = Import-Csv "H:\test\Groups2.csv" 

    foreach ($name in $names.DisplayName) {
        $Sam += Get-ADUser -Filter { Name -like $name } -Properties SamAccountName | Select-Object SamAccountName
    }

    $User =  $Sam

    foreach ($User in $User) {
        Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $secgrp -Members $User
    }

}

$OKButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$OKButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(260,45)
$OKButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,30)
$OKButton.Text = "OK"
$OKButton.Add_Click($test)
$Form.Controls.Add($OKButton)

$Form.Add_KeyDown({
    if ($_.KeyCode -eq "Enter") {
        & $test
    }
})

$Form.Add_KeyDown({
    if ($_.KeyCode -eq "Escape") {
        $Form.Close()
    }
})

$Form.TopMost = $True
$Form.Add_Shown({ $Form.Activate() })
[void] $Form.ShowDialog()
```

Answer (score 4):

You can check the number of Users returned by `Get-ADUser` by using the `Count` property. This will tell you how many objects (users) were returned.

If there is more than 1 user, you can use `Out-GridView` to display a popup dialogue to select the result you want from the list:

[image: Out-GridView example]

By default this allows multiple selections, but adding `-OutputMode Single` will then only allow a single selection to be chosen.

Your script can be updated like this:

```
$test = {
    $secgrp = $textbox.Text
    $Users = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
    $names = Import-Csv "H:\test\Groups2.csv" 

    foreach ($name in $names.DisplayName) {
        $ReturnedUser = Get-ADUser -Filter { Name -like $name } -Properties SamAccountName | Select-Object -ExpandProperty SamAccountName

        if ($ReturnedUser.count > 1) {
            $SelectedUser = $ReturnedUser | Out-GridView -Title "Multiple Users have matched, select User to process" -OutputMode Single
            $null = $Users.Add($SelectedUser) #this syntax surpresses the .Add() from displaying the index of each item added
        }
        else {
            $null = $Users.Add($ReturnedUser)
        }
    }

    foreach ($User in $Users) {
        Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $secgrp -Members $User
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the perfect and right solution, IMHO.  I came here planning to write exactly this answer to the question, good work @James.

Comment: Small update to `Select-Object -ExpandProperty SamAccountName` and also `foreach ($User in $User)` isn't good, so I've updated that too.

Comment: Sorry if I am being very stupid. Still trying to find my feet! :L I tried to insert that snippet of code into my script and it still just added everyone to the group.
So I tried the code just on its out without any of the rest of the script and it errors out. op_addition: string

Comment: No worries James, there is actually an error in the code.  We should be using a `System.Collections.ArrayList` instead of an `Array`, that's why there was this error.  @JamesC., I've edited the code to use an ArrayList instead of an Array, to solve this.

Comment: Thank you, I had noticed that and solved that I'm now having problems with it actually displaying. When I run it the out-grid view doesn't display. If I run the scrip then say out-grid returned users it displays? Thank you so much for your help