# Output to select user in PS Gui from list

Tags: powershell, active-directory

Wonder if someone can help point me in the right direction and assist with getting my PS script to list all names when searching. So i have built a tool which does various AD tasks. I wanted to add the ability to search names rather than having to use `sAMAccountName` as sometimes peoples names are not as obvious. Some googling showed i can use `Out-GridView` to do this. I have written the below for one function but upon testing it fails to do that. It will still work if the username is typed but not list all James's for example. So not sure what i may have wrong here entirely. Code below with what i wrote.

```
#Function checks whether a user is locked in Active Directory
function CheckLocked {
    Try {
        $Result = Get-ADUser -Identity $User.text -Properties Name, LastLogonDate, LockedOut, AccountLockOutTime, Enabled, AccountExpirationDate | select-Object Name, LastLogonDate, LockedOut, AccountLockOutTime, Enabled, AccountExpirationDate
        $Result | Out-GridView -Title 'Locked Accounts'

        if ($Result.count -gt 1) {
            $user.text = $Result | Out-GridView -Title "Multiple Users have matched, select User to process" -OutputMode Single
            $null = $User.Add($user.text) #this syntax surpresses the .Add() from displaying the index of each item added 
        }
        else {
            $null =$user.add($Result)
        }
}
Catch {
        Add-Log -Message ("Error checking account for lockout for " + $user.text)
    # Add the trapped error to log
        Add-Log -Message $_
}
}
```

Thanks in advance all.

Answer (score 1):

Kevlar,

What AlexR is showing is a valid approach. He is just not showing GUI stuff. You just have to refactor/tweak that to your needs.

For example (again not using any Form GUI):

```
# Type in a full or partial name or list of names separated by a space
(Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter a list of names' ) -split '\s' | 
ForEach{Get-LocalUser -Name "*$PSItem*"} 
Enter a list of names: acc

# Results
<#
Name               Enabled Description                                         
----               ------- -----------                                         
DefaultAccount     False   A user account managed by the system.               
WDAGUtilityAccount False   A user account managed and used by the system for...
#>


# Type in a full or partial name or list of names separated by a space
(Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter a list of names' ) -split '\s' | 
ForEach{Get-LocalUser -Name "*$PSItem*"} 
Enter a list of names: administrator

# Results
<#
Name          Enabled Description                                           
----          ------- -----------                                           
Administrator False   Built-in account for administering the computer/domain
#>


# Type in a full or partial name or list of names separated by a space
(Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter a list of names' ) -split '\s' | 
ForEach{Get-LocalUser -Name "*$PSItem*"} 

Enter a list of names: admin gues

# Results
<#
Name          Enabled Description                                             
----          ------- -----------                                             
Administrator False   Built-in account for administering the computer/domain  
Guest         False   Built-in account for guest access to the computer/domain
#>
```

Or with a simple GUI, the results are the same...

```
[void][Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.VisualBasic')

$title = 'User Admin'
$msg   = 'Type in a full or partial name or list of names separated by a space'

[Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::InputBox($msg, $title) -split '\s' |  
ForEach{Get-LocalUser -Name "*$PSItem*"}
```

Also, here is a different cmdlet specifically designed to lookup lockouts.

```
# Get specifics for a module, cmdlet, or function
(Get-Command -Name Search-ADAccount).Parameters
(Get-Command -Name Search-ADAccount).Parameters.Keys
# Results
<#
...
AccountDisabled
AccountExpired
AccountExpiring
AccountInactive
AuthType
ComputersOnly
Credential
DateTime
LockedOut
PasswordExpired
PasswordNeverExpires
ResultPageSize
ResultSetSize
SearchBase
SearchScope
Server
TimeSpan
UsersOnly
#>
Get-help -Name Search-ADAccount -Examples
# Results
<#
Search-ADAccount -AccountDisabled | FT Name,ObjectClass -A
Search-ADAccount -AccountDisabled -UsersOnly | FT Name,ObjectClass -A
Search-ADAccount -AccountExpired | FT Name,ObjectClass -A
Search-ADAccount -AccountExpiring -TimeSpan 6.00:00:00 | FT Name,ObjectClass -A
Search-ADAccount -AccountInactive -TimeSpan 90.00:00:00 | FT Name,ObjectClass -A
Jeff Phillips               user
Search-ADAccount -PasswordExpired | FT Name,ObjectClass -A
Search-ADAccount -PasswordNeverExpires | FT Name,ObjectClass -A
Search-ADAccount -LockedOut | FT Name,ObjectClass -A
Search-ADAccount -AccountDisabled -ComputersOnly | FT Name,ObjectClass -A
Search-ADAccount -AccountExpiring -DateTime "3/18/2009" | FT Name,ObjectClass -A
Search-AdAccount -AccountDisabled -SearchBase "DC=AppNC" -Server "FABRIKAM-SRV1:60000"
#>
Get-help -Name Search-ADAccount -Full
Get-help -Name Search-ADAccount -Online

# Results
<#
-LockedOut
Returns all account objects that have been locked out.
#>
```

Comment: Think i may have explained what i want wrong here. I am looking to achieve something similar to here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50295022/powershell-how-to-get-powershell-to-give-you-the-option-to-select-the-right-use  

in that i want to be able to type 'James' in my search box and PS to return the 'Out-GridView' like shown in the link where it lists the users then you select the one you want the required info click ok then it runs the command and displays as it was before i looked to add this. Equally if 'sAMAccountName' is used it will just show the results.

Comment: Sure, I get that, and what I am showing is that exact thing without using OGV. YOu can just add the OGV as needed.

Answer (score 0):

If I get you correct, you need to find all Jameses. Try this:

```
$ADName1 = "James"
$ADName = "*$ADName1*"
[array]$Result = (Get-ADUser -Filter {Name -like $ADName} -Properties Name, LastLogonDate, LockedOut, AccountLockOutTime, Enabled, AccountExpirationDate)
if($Result.Count -gt 1) {
    #Lots of them
    foreach($AdUser in $Result) {
        if($AdUser.LockedOut -eq $true) {
            Write-Output $AdUser.Name+"("+$AdUser.SamAccountName+") is locked"
        }
    }
} else {
    if($Result.LockedOut -eq $true) {
            Write-Output $Result.Name+"("+$Result.SamAccountName+") is locked"
    }
}
```

Comment: Well not quite. This is in a GUI so the name will be put in a text box. Normally in format First.Lastname it will find it. I wanted it to also work if i typed say a first name and return all these names.

Comment: The output also displayed other info as well when checking so ideally if using the search it will show multiple names they can then select the correct one and it then outputs the Grid-view it was before.